# boost shared_from_this<>()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

could someone summarize in a few succinct words how the boost `shared_from_this<>()` smart pointer should be used, particularly from the perspective of registering handlers in the io_service using the bind function.

EDIT: Some of the responses have asked for more context. Basically, I'm looking for "gotchas", counter-intuitive behaviour people have observed using this mechanism.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? It's hard to answer an undirected question.

Comment: The only way I could attempt to illustrate an example was by pasting in reams of code, which, being boost code, is dense enough as it is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The biggest "gotcha" I've run into is that it's illegal to call shared_from_this from the constructor. This follows directly from the rule that a shared_ptr to the object must exist before you can call shared_from_this.

Comment: +1 good advice, typically I make my constructor provide and provide a static `shared_ptr<Type> create` method.

Comment: I think you meant you make your constructor private.

Answer (score 14):

From my understanding, sometimes in your code you want a class to offer up `shared_ptr`'s to itself so that other parts of your code can obtain shared_ptr's to an object of your class after it has been constructed.

The problem is that if your class just has a `shared_ptr<>` to itself as a member variable, it will never get automatically destructed, since there is always "one last reference" hanging around to itself.  Inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` gives your class an automatic method which not only returns a `shared_ptr`, but only holds a weak shared pointer as a member variable so as not to affect the reference count.  This way, your class will be freed as usual when the last reference to it is gone.

I've never used it, but this is my understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 11):

`shared_from_this<>` is used if an object wants to get access to a `shared_ptr<>` pointing to itself.

Usually an object only knows about the implicit `this` pointer, but not about any `shared_ptr<>` managing it. Also, `this` cannot easily be converted into a `shared_ptr<>` that shares ownership with other existing `shared_ptr<>` instances, so there is no easy way for an object to get a valid `shared_ptr<>` to itself.

`shared_from_this<>` can be used to solve this problem. For example:

```
struct A : boost::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
   server *io;
   // ...

   void register_self() {
      io->add_client(shared_from_this());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

the `boost::asio::io_service` [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) documentation explains it fairly well

> The destruction sequence described
>   above permits programs to simplify
>   their resource management by using
>   shared_ptr<>. Where an object's
>   lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a
>   connection (or some other sequence of
>   asynchronous operations), a shared_ptr
>   to the object would be bound into the
>   handlers for all asynchronous
>   operations associated with it. This
>   works as follows:
>
> - When a single connection ends, all associated asynchronous operations
>     complete. The corresponding handler
>     objects are destroyed, and all
>     shared_ptr references to the objects
>     are destroyed.
> - To shut down the whole program, the io_service function stop() is called
>     to terminate any run() calls as soon
>     as possible. The io_service destructor
>     defined above destroys all handlers,
>     causing all shared_ptr references to
>     all connection objects to be
>     destroyed.

Typically your objects will chain asynchronous operations where the handlers are bound to member functions using `boost::bind` and `boost::shared_from_this()`. There are some [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp) that use this concept.

Comment: You're answer finally explained asio examples to me... Particularly what happens if there is an error in the connection and the http server example from asio.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff is missing from some of the comments above. Here's an example that helped me:

[Boost enable_shared_from_this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)

For me, I was struggling with errors about bad weak pointers. You HAVE to allocate your object in a shared_ptr fashion:

```
class SyncSocket: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<SyncSocket>
```

And allocate one like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SyncSocket> socket(new SyncSocket);
```

Then you can do things like:

```
socket->connect(...);
```

Lots of examples show you how to use shared_from_this() something like this:

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, receiveBuffer, haveData,
        boost::bind(&SyncSocket::dataReceived, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

But was missing for me was using a shared_ptr to allocate the object to begin with.